# Accessing Mongo nested decimal objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, typescript

I am using MongoDB (not local) and have an entry in the collection as follows.

```
name: "fancy name" 
description: "fancy description" 
category: "fancy category" 
options: Object 
   small: 5.35
   medium: 9.25
   large: 16.00
```

However when I try to access the 'options' I get another object instead of the number listed. For example, if I do the following:

```
console.log(item.options)
```

I see:

```
small: {$numberDecimal: "5.35"}
medium: {$numberDecimal: "9.25"}
large: {$numberDecimal: "16.00"}
```

So my question, if I want to access the ACTUAL NUMBER in my code (typescript) how can that be done? When I read the data from the database I read them into an interface which has the following fields:

```
export interface Item {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    category: string;
    options?: ItemOptions;
}

export interface ItemOptions {
    small: number;
    medium: number;
    large: number;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(Object.values(item.options))`? What does that show?

Comment: Yes it shows the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you have figured it out by now, but have you tried `.toJSON()` of the object when you retrieve it from the database? The other possibility is to use `.lean()` when you are getting it.

`db.collection.find().lean()` if you're using the `mongoose`.